# Python - Apscheduler not stopping a job even after using 'remove_job'

Tags: python, apscheduler

This is my code

I'm using the `remove_job` and the `shutdown` functions of the scheduler to stop a job, but it keeps on executing.

What is the correct way to stop a job from executing any further?

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BlockingScheduler

def job_function():
    print "job executing"


scheduler = BlockingScheduler(standalone=True)
scheduler.add_job(job_function, 'interval', seconds=1, id='my_job_id')


scheduler.start()
scheduler.remove_job('my_job_id')
scheduler.shutdown()
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Simply ask the scheduler to remove the job inside the `job_function` using the `remove_function` as @Akshay Pratap Singh Pointed out correctly, that the control never returns back to `start()`

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BlockingScheduler

count = 0

def job_function():
    print "job executing"
    global count, scheduler

    # Execute the job till the count of 5 
    count = count + 1
    if count == 5:
        scheduler.remove_job('my_job_id')


scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(job_function, 'interval', seconds=1, id='my_job_id')


scheduler.start()
```

Answer (score 8):

As you are using [BlockingScheduler](http://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/schedulers/blocking.html) , so first you know it's nature.

So, basically `BlockingScheduler` is a scheduler which runs in foreground(i.e **start()** will block the program).In laymen terms, It runs in the foreground, so when you call **start()**, the call never returns. That's why all lines which are followed by **start()** are never called, due to which your scheduler never stopped.

> > BlockingScheduler can be useful if you want to use APScheduler as a standalone scheduler (e.g. to build a daemon).

---

**Solution**

If you want to stop your scheduler after running some code, then you should opt for other types of scheduler listed in `ApScheduler` [docs](http://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide.html#choosing-the-right-scheduler-job-stores-and-executors).

I recommend `BackgroundScheduler`, if you want the scheduler to run in the background inside your application/program which you can **pause**, **resume** and **remove** at anytime, when you need it.

Comment: The Code does'nt execute a single job at all, when using BackgroundScheduler this way -> http://pastebin.com/xDAJAXvT  What am i doing wrong?

Comment: With BackgroundScheduler, start() does not block so your main script ENDS, effectively stopping your application. Surely you don't want to stop the job right after starting the scheduler, so what is the real world scenario here?

Comment: @AlexGrönholm I simply want to schedule a job running every interval, even if the main script ends. I'd like to stop the job eventually inside the associated function

Comment: I think the other option is to throw it in a try/catch and look for specific exceptions (like keyboard interrupt) to stop the scheduler.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved the problem. Pay attention to the position where the code `schedule.shutdown()` is located!

```
def do_something():
    global schedule
    print("schedule execute")
    # schedule.remove_job(id='rebate')
    schedule.shutdown(wait=False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    global schedule
    schedule = BlockingScheduler()
    schedule.add_job(do_something, 'cron', id='rebate', month=12, day=5, hour=17, minute=47, second=35)
    schedule.start()
    print('over')
```

Answer (score 0):

The scheduler needs to be stopped from another thread. The thread in which `scheduler.start()` is called gets blocked by the scheduler. The lines that you've written after `scheduler.start()` is unreachable code.

Comment: please clarify what additional value ad given by this post from others.